# Flask Matplotlib Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask

Unable to dynamically update data visualization charts via user input.

make_visual takes info, creates matplotlib visuals, then saves them in the static location.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def make_visual(nums):
    a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h = nums
    turn_labels = "A", "B"
    turn_size = [a,b]
    goes_labels = "1", "2"
    goes_size = [c,d]
    method_labels = "Moo", "Bark", "Meow"
    method_size = [g, f, e]
    fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    ax1.pie(turn_size, labels=turn_labels, autopct='%1.1f%%', startangle=90)
    ax1.axis('equal')
    plt.savefig("static/graph.png")
    fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
    ax2.pie(goes_size, labels=goes_labels, autopct='%1.1f%%', startangle=90)
    ax2.axis('equal')
    plt.savefig("static/goes.png")
    fig3, ax3 = plt.subplots()
    ax3.pie(method_size, labels=method_labels, autopct='%1.1f%%', startangle=90)
    ax3.axis('equal')
    plt.savefig("static/method.png")

make_visual([0.50, 0.50, 0.4, 0.6, 0.43, 0.3, 0.27, 14.511904761904763])
```

^
When this runs on it's own in the command line, it works.
Does not work in the Flask function.
If I remove make_visual, the info goes through to the results.html page as intended.

I am unsure as to why I am unable to dynamically create, save, then render the page with the visuals current from the static folder.

```
@app.route('/results', methods=['POST'])
def results():
    stats = request.form['data']
    info = get_stats(stats)
    unstr = stats.split(',')
    title = make_string(unstr[0], unstr[1])
    make_visual(info)
    return render_template('results.html', stats=title, data=info)
```

Below is results.html.

```
{% block content %}
<div class='container-fluid text-center'>
        <h1 class='p-2 m-2'>Results</h1>
        <h3 class='text-success'>{{ stats }}</h3>
        <h4>{{ data }}</h4>
    <div class="row mt-2">
        <div class="col-lg-4 p-1">
            <img class='img-fluid' src="/static/graph.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 p-1">
            <img class='img-fluid' src="/static/goes.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 p-1">
            <img class='img-fluid' src="/static/method.png">
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

For best results, show code that demonstrates the problem, with extraneous details removed and in a full enough form that it can be run. Often the exercise of doing that is sufficient to unearth the cause.

However, getting matplotlib working with Flask involves a trick. I'm guessing that after

```
import matplotlib
```

there's no

```
matplotlib.use('agg')
```

without with matplotlib will attempt to use tkinter to render, which leads to sadness when trying to work with Flask.

Comment: Good guess and idea.
I added the make_visual function to the question.